# Problem with pageviewer webpart in sharepoint2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using a pageviewer webpart to display a .htm page which is present in a document library in sharepoint 2010.

It is asking me to download the page instead of diplaying in the page

But in MOSS 2007 it is working fine(I mean it is displaying in the page)

Please suggest me the solution

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SP2010 has restrictions on displaying or opening some files. So for that, You need to go to central administration and check the "Browser File Handling" to "Permissive" for that web application's general settings.

I think it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

There is a better way to handle "Browser File Handle" issue. Take a look at my blog here: http://www.pdfsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2010-and-pdf-integration-series-part-1/

Solution #2 addresses Pdf extension without exposing entire Web Application to "Permissive" browsing. Setting "Browsing File Handle" to "permissive" opens too many vulnerabilities with other file extensions.

Thanks,

Dmitry

Comment: are you somehow related to JnJ or TCS?

Comment: 404 broken link
edit: actually the whole domain is down